# Compatibility between a gRPC server in Go and a client in Python

Tags: python, go, grpc

I want to know about the compatibility about a gRPC service in Go and a client in Python.

For instance [if the service is implemented in Go](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/go.html), it will have signatures like this:

```
...

func (s *routeGuideServer) GetFeature(ctx context.Context, point *pb.Point) (*pb.Feature, error) {
        ...
}
...

func (s *routeGuideServer) ListFeatures(rect *pb.Rectangle, stream pb.RouteGuide_ListFeaturesServer) error {
        ...
}
...

func (s *routeGuideServer) RecordRoute(stream pb.RouteGuide_RecordRouteServer) error {
        ...
}
...

func (s *routeGuideServer) RouteChat(stream pb.RouteGuide_RouteChatServer) error {
        ...
}
```

Note how `error` objects are returned.

Now, if I have to [implement the client in Python it will be something like this](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html):

```
feature = stub.GetFeature(point)
for received_route_note in stub.RouteChat(sent_route_note_iterator):
```

What happens to the `error` field that is returned by the Go service implementation? If there is an error from the server side how can it be handled in the Python client?

Answer (score 3):

gRPC provides error handling that fits the language being used.

As you noted, in a [Go server](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/8e187527667212cfe1b2b64727c7f83e95c6591f/examples/route_guide/server/server.go#L126) you return an error:

```
func (s *routeGuideServer) RouteChat(stream pb.RouteGuide_RouteChatServer) error {
for {
    in, err := stream.Recv()
    if err == io.EOF {
        return nil
    }
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    ...
```

In a Python client, you execute the API call in a `try` statement (contrived example, since the official documentation doesn't demonstrate this):

```
while True:
  try:
    received_route_note = stub.RouteChat(sent_route_note_iterator)
  except grpc.Error as e:
    print(e.details())
    break
```

Conversely, in a Python server, you set the context and, optionally, raise an exception:

- example from the [Python Generated Code Reference](https://grpc.io/docs/reference/python/generated-code.html):

  ```
  def TellFortune(self, request, context):
    """Returns the horoscope and zodiac sign for the given month and day.
    errors: invalid month or day, fortune unavailable
    """
    context.set_code(grpc.StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED)
    context.set_details('Method not implemented!')
    raise NotImplementedError('Method not implemented!')
  ```
- example from the [grpc repository](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio_tests/tests/testing/_server_application.py)

  ```
  def UnUn(self, request, context):
    if _application_common.UNARY_UNARY_REQUEST == request:
        return _application_common.UNARY_UNARY_RESPONSE
    else:
        context.set_code(grpc.StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT)
        context.set_details('Something is wrong with your request!')
        return services_pb2.Down()
  ```

And in a [Go client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/8e187527667212cfe1b2b64727c7f83e95c6591f/examples/route_guide/client/client.go#L119) an `error` object is (one of) the result parameters:

```
stream, err := client.RouteChat(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("%v.RouteChat(_) = _, %v", client, err)
}
```

---

It's unfortunate that the official documentation doesn't seem to explicitly cover error handling practices.

A good 3rd party reference I found is at http://avi.im/grpc-errors/